# How do I list out the new TCP connections using Python?

Tags: python, psutil

I have a code which lists out all the tcp connections:

```
import psutil
for connection in (psutil.net_connections(kind='tcp')):
    print connection[5]
```

However, I need to list out the freshly added as well. I would, then, run the script which would run the code in the `while(1)` loop and keep on checking the new connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your connections in two different [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and compare them

```
import psutil
import time

initial = frozenset(psutil.net_connections(kind='tcp'))
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    current = frozenset(psutil.net_connections(kind='tcp'))
    print(current.difference(initial))
```